# Azure - Buy custom domain not working with .NL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I'm trying to add a custom domain to my azure subscription.

For example: whateverexample.nl (All examples and screenshots below are actually done using this example domain).

I go to my appservice, select Custom Domains on the left hand side, scroll down and click "buy domain" (with the large plus-sign). A new page shows where I can register a new domain, but when I type my domainname, it just keeps on loading forever.
[image: Loading Forever]

I tried typing my domainname without ".nl", and it suggests a couple of things, but NOT the .nl domain, in fact, the suggestions it's giving me don't even make sense, because all microsofts supported top level domainnames (com, net, co.uk, org, nl, in, biz, org.uk, and co.in) are available for whateverexample (check it out, they actually are):
[image: Suggestions]

Oh, and notice that "Click to try the newer version of the App Service Domains create experience.". Yes, I tried that. Exactly the same problem.

---

So I started looking around.

1. The domainname is in fact free:
   [image: whois domain lookup]
2. My appservice plan does not have a spending limit:
   [image: Appservice plan]
3. Another registrar is ready to charge me when I try to order the domain, so everything, acorrding to them, is in order and the domain could be mine in one click (the large green button means "finalize order"):
   [image: Registrar lets me register]
4. Whatever I type, when I add ".nl" to it, it just stops working (stops showing me suggestions) and yeah, the suggestions in the first place don't make sense (again).

[image: .NL is not working]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

nl domains is one of the domain types that are available for purchace through Azure.

The Foundation for Internet Domain Registration in the Netherlands (SIDN) is responsible for the registration of domains within .nl.

It may be that the integration with SIDN had problems when you tried to register the domain.

Comment: Yes, must be something like this. I had trouble with a few of the whois sites as well. I will try again in the coming week and if it's solved, all mark this as the answer. Seems right.